# What is the most effective method to prevent a soggy shortcrust quiche base?

Tags: baking, pastry

I have seen two methods to counter this. One is the traditional way of pricking the base with a fork, then blind baking at 200C with weights etc. for 10 minutes, then giving an additional 5 minutes without the weights, then add the filling.

The other is to prick the base as before, seal with beaten egg white, place in the freezer for 30-60 minutes, then add the filling.

The latter to me, seems to be a good way of using up the leftover egg white when making the classic custard filling in a quiche, but does it deliver better results than the traditional blind baking method?

Comment: if you blind bake, you could still seal it with egg white.  (20 min of baking is faster than 30-60 minutes of filling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal experience, the freezing method has never worked well. I have a traditional quiche pan - white porcelain with vertical fluted walls - and it gets very cold in the freezer. No matter how I have played with temperature and top/bottom heater setting afterwards, I have never been able to compensate for the effect of the cold porcelain (a bit like the opposite of a preheated pizza stone) - I always got an underbaked soggy crust bottom with crispy to overbaked crust walls, and a gradient in the filling's baking.

I can imagine that the freezing method might work for people using American pie tins or similar, but it has a serious disadvantage with a porcelain pan.

Answer (score 1):

My method is like your first one, except after the first 10 minutes of baking, seal with beaten egg, and then bake for an additional 5 minutes to dry it.